# How to remove search reference link above methods and attributes in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, editor

I want to remove the reference link above each attribute and each method,(this link finds method calls in the code for example),
I have this problem which cause eclipse to be very uncomfortable to use.

I . tried playing with content assistance preferences

```
@Autowired
1 reference <----- want to remove this
private UserRepository userRepository;

@Autowired
1 reference <----- want to remove this
private BrandRepository brandRepository;
```

I expected eclipse editor to be without any links

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have **Code** **Mining** enabled. [You can turn it off](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.10/jdt.php#jdt-codemining) in your Preferences.

[image]

Comment: Thank youuuu, you Helped me Alooot